# Python prompt printing multi line comment with extra characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Prompt_Toolkit to create a terminal like program. One of the commands I have is `help`. Basically you enter help and it will return a multiline comment. But when it is being printed, the formatting is being interpreted weird.

[image]

As you can see, when I type prompt I will return the `__doc__` string which is just a formatted string with tabs.

I am not sure what the `^I` are doing in there and what I should be looking up to get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the terminal's encoding differs from yours, so it outputs certain characters as `^I` as a means to represent tabs. Nothing to be worried about.

Comment: It is when I don't want that to be there.

Comment: There isn't really a way to universally change the style of it, unless you change the encoding of the terminal itself.

Comment: What terminal are you using?

Comment: I am using Prompt_Toolkit

Comment: If you don't want to change any terminal settings, my advice to you is to replace the tabs with spaces.